# Why is jQuery hide not immediate (delayed by page load)

Tags: jquery, hide, delay

## What I have:

I'm using jQuery to hide the last few list items in an unordered list.

## My problem:

The list items appear on the page until the page loads and the jQuery kicks in (which is undesirable).

**EDIT: I cannot edit the HTML. Since I can't selectively add classes I can therefore not rely on pure CSS. I'm using a jQuery selector to target the last two list items.**

## My code:

Whether I use the hide() function or addclass() + display:none, I experience the same problem.

```
<ul id="some_menu">
    <li><a href="#">Enkidu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gilgamesh</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Epic</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sumeria</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Anunnaki</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        //jQuery('ul#some_menu li:gt(2)').addClass("hide_menu_link");
        jQuery('ul#some_menu li:gt(2)').hide();
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .hide_menu_link{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

Here's the code on JSFIDDLE though it doesn't reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/dominornovus/pB8Mb/2/

Comment: My suggestion.. hide them all by default and then just show the items you want to show

Comment: @Dementic - I'm restricted from modifying the HTML which prevents me selectively adding classes. How else can I target the last two list items? Isn't gt() a jQuery selector?

Comment: @udidu - Thanks for the suggestion but as I've asked Lostdreamer, how do I achieve the inverse/reverse/opposite of the li:gt(2) selector?

Comment: it looks like you always want to show only the first three items.. right? so use `jQuery('ul#some_menu li:lt(3)').show();`

Comment: @udidu - Thank you. I wasn't aware that gt = greater than and therefore its obvious (in hindsight) opposite is lt. Completed solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/dominornovus/pB8Mb/5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `jQuery(document).ready` you are telling jQuery to wait for the document to be ready before executing. So, it will, indeed, wait for the page to be ready (loaded) before it takes action.

Like others said, if you want some items to be hidden at page start and some other to be available, you should reverse the logic, start with everything hidden and then show want you want to display when the document is ready.

Comment: This is a solid idea but what would the inverse/reverse/opposite of the li:gt(2) selector?

Comment: Quickly I would say $('ul#some_menu li:lt(3)')

Comment: "Reversing the logic" worked like a charm. This circumvents the problem I was experiencing with the load delay. Much thanks. Completed solution: http://jsfiddle.net/dominornovus/pB8Mb/5/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use CSS to hide these elements if you want them hidden on load. Its generally a good idea to wait until the page has loaded before you start manipulating it with javascript otherwise the elements you are trying to hide may not have loaded yet.

There are a number of ways you can hide them with CSS depending on your requirements.

`display: none;` is what jQuery is setting as an inline style when you call `.hide()`

Comment: Please see the edit I've made to my question. I cannot modify the HTML  therefore selectively adding classes/styles via just mark-up and CSS is not a solution. I'm using jQuery specifically to target the last two list items using the gt() selector.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because jQuery is client-side executed, so, firstly the code comes from the server and it shows it to your browser, after the DOM is loaded and ready jQuery will be executed, so, it will be always like this, unless you hide it from the server-side language or with a css rule.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the following?: "unless you hide it from the server-side language or with a css rule".

Comment: I mean, you hide it from your code (in case that list you print it with php, .net, java or any other server-side lang.) If is a pure html then do it with css, because you dont have to wait for the DOM. If you use jquery, doesnt matter if use a .hide or a css('display','none') , still, you will be able to use jQuery until the DOM is ready, and it will depend of your internet , how fast or slow is to let user see the element you want to hide or not